# JGoodies Forms Demo code

Tags: java, swing, layout, jgoodies

I must admit the fact Forms layout does save loads of time, wrt other Swing layouts. I did try out other examples from http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Swing-Library/jgoodies-forms/Catalogjgoodies-forms.htm and worked fine. However, i was more interested in the forms-demo code from the actual developer, is it available ? Couldn't find them, other than the executable jar file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you see the [com.jgoodies.forms.tutorial.building](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Swing-Library/jgoodies-forms/com.jgoodies.forms.tutorial.building.htm) link in that page?  Seems to link to a number of source code listings.

But see also the Java version of the Forms Demo at [JGoodies|Downloads|Applications](http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/index.html).

---

The site seems to have been reorganized since my last visit, but you can probably find those things from http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/

Comment: @tokam  & it took almost 2 minutes of looking around the site to find the downloads page..

Comment: Dead link in the accepted answer, http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/libraries/ doesn't let you download the source code for the form demos, http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/demos/ either.